How to find gaps in an int column (grouped by another column) in MySQL?
There are numerous SQL questions and answers about finding gaps in sequences, but I could not find any that have the wrinkle my situation has: I need to group the sequence by another column.
My table (simplified)
id | parent_id | list_index
1  | 987       | 0
2  | 987       | 1
3  | 987       | 2

4  | 654       | 0
5  | 654       | 2

7  | 321       | 1
8  | 321       | 2
9  | 321       | 4
10 | 321       | 5

I added the empty lines to visualize the grouping.
The business rule is that for any parent_id there should be a set of rows with list_index values in a contiguous sequence starting at 0. However, the data has gaps and it's those gaps I need to find. Specifically, I need to identify the parent_ids that have a gap.
In the sample data above, I would need the query to identify parent ids 654 and 321 because 654 is missing a row with list_index 1 and parent 321 is missing rows with list_index 0 and 3. Parent id 987 should not be included because it's rows have a contiguous sequence.
I do not care what the gap looks like (eg, where it starts or ends), just which parentids are missing 1 or more rows.

Get the count of rows for each parent_id, and the difference between max and min list_index. If the count is less than difference+1, there's a gap. E.g. for 654 the count is 2, and the difference is 2, and 2 < 2+1.

But for 987, the count is 3 and the difference is 2. 3 == 2+1, so no gap.

For sequence (1,2,3,4) count is 4 and (difference+1)=4.  We can compare count and max(list_index). Min always mast be 0. count(*)=(max(list_index)+1) - no gaps.

Window function row_number should make this easy.

I didn't notice that the sequence has to start at 0. That makes it even easier. Just compare MAX(list_index)+1 with COUNT(*), you don't need the difference.

@barmar, There's some risk to that with potential duplicate list_index values should they exist, otherwise yeah that would work too https://dbfiddle.uk/-m3_Hph4 works... https://dbfiddle.uk/fngVp1AX doesn't but it skippes zero and just has 1,2. max

@xQbert Yes, I assumed there could only be gaps, not duplicates

@xQbert No. MAX(list_index) + 1 == 3, which is not equal to COUNT(*)

I already ran a query to find duplicates (and then fixed them one-by-one), so there are no duplicates in my data. Having said that, I think the question is more generally useful and interesting if there can be duplicates.

Why do you care? id is short for identifier and you’re not going to identify a record better or worse because the number is different.

DBFiddleUk Demo
Premise: use a window function Row Number() and order by your list index and identify records where the row_number assigned-1 isn't equal to the list index.
CTE- your data
CTE2- your data with a row_numer assigned
Final query against CTE2 gives you the group and a count of records which don't match.
With CTE as(
Select 1 ID, 987 parent_Id, 0 list_index UNION ALL
Select 2 ID, 987 parent_Id, 1 list_index UNION ALL
Select 3 ID, 987 parent_Id, 2 list_index UNION ALL
Select 4 ID, 654 parent_Id, 0 list_index UNION ALL
Select 5 ID, 654 parent_Id, 2 list_index UNION ALL
Select 7 ID, 321 parent_Id, 1 list_index UNION ALL
Select 8 ID, 321 parent_Id, 2 list_index UNION ALL
Select 9 ID, 321 parent_Id, 4 list_index UNION ALL
Select 10 ID, 321 parent_Id, 5 list_index),
CTE2 as (
SELECT A.*, row_number() over (partition by parent_ID order by list_index)-1 RN
  FROM CTE A)

SELECT Parent_ID, count(*) from CTE2 where Rn <> List_index
GROUP BY Parent_ID

Giving us:
+-----------+----------+
| Parent_ID | count(*) |
+-----------+----------+
|       321 |        4 |
|       654 |        1 |
+-----------+----------+

----To address comment  replace [YourTableName] with your table name.
This uses a "Temporary" table/CTE to generate a recordset containing the row_number for each parent_ID ordered by the list_index-1 for that parent_ID.  It then runs a select against that temporary table identifying those parents whose row_number and list_index do not match; groups by parent_id and counts the occurrences of values not matching.
WITH CTE2 as (
SELECT A.*, row_number() over (partition by parent_ID order by list_index)-1 RN
  FROM [YourTableName] A)

SELECT Parent_ID, count(*) from CTE2 where Rn <> List_index
GROUP BY Parent_ID


How would I do this in an interactive session with my live DB? The "noise" of WITH...AS makes it hard to see the final solution.

Just eliminate the first block with CTE...(), and change the CTE2 to select from your tablename instead of CTE.  Rest of it would remain unchanged.

Gaps in your case can be considered separately for each group (parent_id).
Then the task becomes a regular gap-finding task again.
See examples.

Full details about gap

select *
from(
  select *
    ,case when prev_list_index is null and list_index<>0 then 'start not 0'
        when (prev_list_index+1)<>list_index then concat('missing ',(list_index-1))
     else null
    end isGap
  from(
    select * 
      ,lag(list_index)over(partition by parent_id order by list_index) prev_list_index
    from test
  )a
)b
where isGap is not null

Output is



id
parent_id
list_index
prev_list_index
isGap




7
321
1
null
start not 0


9
321
4
2
missing 3


5
654
2
0
missing 1




Or take 1 row for parent_id

select parent_id,min(id) id,group_concat(isGap order by isGap) gaps
from(
  select *
    ,case when prev_list_index is null and list_index<>0 then 0
        when (prev_list_index+1)<>list_index then (list_index-1)
     else null
    end isGap
  from(
    select * 
      ,lag(list_index)over(partition by parent_id order by list_index) prev_list_index
    from test
  )a
)b
where isGap is not null
group by parent_id




parent_id
id
gaps




321
7
0,3


654
5
1




Query sample without any details

select parent_id
from test
group by parent_id
having count(*)<>(max(list_index)+1)




parent_id




654


321




We can use math and partitioning to solve this.

We will need a table expression to use some window functions: "indexed_data"
Track a row number and partition by parent_id
Track the lowest list_index for a parent_id (we will use this as a counting base to detect sequentiality from this arbitrary starting point)
New table expression "gap_check" that looks for all parent ids where the actual list_index does not equal the expected list index (should the numbers be sequential) - hence indicating that the row is not sequential
Distinctly display all parent ids that passed the gap_check and therefor have gaps

WITH indexed_data AS (SELECT id,
                             parent_id,
                             list_index,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY list_index) AS rn,
                             MIN(list_index) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id)                  AS min_list_index
                      FROM your_table),
     gap_check AS (SELECT parent_id FROM indexed_data WHERE list_index <> (min_list_index + rn - 1))
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id
FROM gap_check;

